# how to exit from multiple loops in python

Tags: python-2.7

In my code below, I keep getting an error that I cant tell how to fix it.
See code:

```
def WordSelector():
    global pattern
    words = [location]
    corpus = " ".join(words)
    sentences1 = re.split(r'\.', corpus)
    name17 = [name66, name666, name67, name68, name69, name612]
    k1 = iter(name17)
    keyword = next(k1)
    pattern1 = keyword

    class LocalBreak(Exception):
        pass
        try:
            for pattern1 in name17:
                for sentence in sentences1:
                    if pattern1 in sentence:
                        print 'code'
                        raise LocalBreak()
        except LocalBreak:
            pass


WordSelector()
```

I keep getting this error:

```
"C:\Python27\synonyms3.py", line 72, in LocalBreak
    except LocalBreak:
NameError: free variable 'LocalBreak' referenced before assignment in enclosing scope
```

Comment: correct code's parenthess

Comment: @Martin, do you mean the one on print?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whole `try/except` block is defined inside `LocalBreak` body, where you cannot reference class itself (since it's definition is not yet done).

Simply indent your code correctly and do your looping in fuction body, not in custom Exception definition scope.

```
def WordSelector():
    global pattern
    words = [location]
    corpus = " ".join(words)
    sentences1 = re.split(r'\.', corpus)
    name17 = [name66, name666, name67, name68, name69, name612]
    k1 = iter(name17)
    keyword = next(k1)
    pattern1 = keyword

    class LocalBreak(Exception):
        pass

    try:
        for pattern1 in name17:
            for sentence in sentences1:
                if pattern1 in sentence:
                    print 'code'
                    raise LocalBreak()
    except LocalBreak:
        pass


WordSelector()
```

Comment: I have run the code online and it is fine and works, but when I use it in my source code, i get a repated print that seems that break or LocalBreak does not stop it. Let me check my lines again. Regards

Comment: in the words section, i put a paragraph from an sqilte Db. In the print section, this is what I have: print ''.join([" ".join([sentences1[m-1],j]) for m,j in enumerate(sentences1) if pattern1 in word_tokenize(j)])